# Test: Focussing an element doesn't trigger the CSS update based on the :focus pseudo class

Tags: css, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, jsdom

## What do I want to do?

Using the CSS pseudo class `:focus` to determine whether an element has the style `display: block` or `none`.

**It works perfectly fine in the browser!**

## What is not working ?

I'm running a Test with `@testing-library/react` to check whether or not the element is visible, based on the focused element. I can focus the element, but the other ones styling still hasn't changed.

I created the same example using the `:checked` pseudo class. This is working!

## What are my questions?

- How do I make it work?
- Is it an issue with jsdom (my guess), or jest, or testing-library?

## Example

You can use the following https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-leavitt-odukyk to check it out. Both examples (`:focus` and `:checked`) are present. Both work fine in the browser. But only the `:checked` test case is successful. (The css is manually added to the tests, because CSS that is imported in React components, isn't automatically added to jsdom.)

```
// App.js
<input
  id="focus_input"
  data-testid="focus_input"
  type="text"
  defaultValue="Focus me"
/>{" "}
<label id="focus_label" data-testid="focus_label">
  Focus input to hide
</label>

//styles.css
#focus_input:focus + #focus_label {
  display: none;
}

//App.test.js
test("Hide on focus", () => {
  renderWithStyle("#focus_input:focus + #focus_label { display: none; }");

  expect(screen.getByTestId("focus_label")).toBeVisible();

  act(() => {
    screen.getByTestId("focus_input").focus();
  });
  expect(screen.getByTestId("focus_input")).toHaveFocus();

  expect(screen.getByTestId("focus_label")).toHaveStyle({ display: "none" });
  expect(screen.getByTestId("focus_label")).not.toBeVisible();
});
```

Comment: Do you have configured moduleNameMapper in your package.json?

Comment: @Pterrat No. In my example App, I'm using a standard CRA setup, that doesn't use moduleNameMapper.

Comment: I created an [issue at @testing-library/react](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/1053) now.

Comment: That let to an [issue at jsdom/jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/3359).